# WearableListenerService binding/unbinding continuously

Tags: android, service, wear-os, sony-smartwatch

I made a simple smartwatch app that connects to the phone to send some data. However, it continously binds and unbinds causing a lot of lag. Logcat shows

```
01-10 22:26:17.780 13094-17893/com.verbraeken.joost V/WearableLS: bindService:  com.verbraeken.joost/.WearListenerService
01-10 22:26:17.783 13094-17893/com.verbraeken.joost V/WearableLS: unbindService: com.verbraeken.joost/.WearListenerService
```

In the manifest the service is declared as:

```
<service android:name="WearListenerService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED"/>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED"/>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.CAPABILITY_CHANGED"/>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.CHANNEL_EVENT"/>
    <data android:path="/WEAR_ORIENTATION" android:host="*" android:scheme="wear"/>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

The service itself does extend WearableListenerService and has nothing more than an onMessageReceived method.

What could be the reason that the service binds/unbinds approximately 50 times per second?

Comment: Which Sony Smartwatch?

Comment: The Sony Smartwatch 3

Answer (score 1):

It is a default behavior (bind and unbind) of the service, based from the documentation - [Sending and Syncing Data](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html):

> ### WearableListenerService (for services)
>
> Extending [WearableListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService.html) lets you listen for important data layer events in a service. The system manages the lifecycle of the [WearableListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService.html), **binding to the service when it needs to send data items or messages and unbinding the service when no work is needed**.

Kindly check your implementation, to verify the error you are encountering (bind/unbind x times per second).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Is there a way to let the service be bound until I tell it to unbind?